# SMS Gateway in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, sms-gateway, maui-blazor

This is code i am using to implement Plivo SMS gateway in blazor application , working on .net 7 and visual studio version is 2022 community version  [image]

this is the issue i have been facing in console [image]

kindly give suggestions to implement integrate SMS in Blazor Web and .net Maui Blazor applications

Comment: You have CORS Error, and you need to check plivo document.

Answer (score 0):

After adding Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly library, try setting SetBrowserRequestMode to no-cors.

```
request.SetBrowserRequestMode(BrowserRequestMode.NoCors);
```

Comment: adding `request.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`  dint work any other approaches for sms integration

Comment: Try updated solution